# Capture event after sorting on datatable with jquery

Tags: firefox, sorting, jquery, datatables

I've an issue with a datable (http://www.datatables.net), jQuery and Firefox.

I've a jQuery datatable (`id="equipmentList"`)  with a button above:

```
<html:button styleId="deleteButton" property="delete" value="<%= buttonDelete %>" disabled="disabled" />
```

When i'm sorting a column on the datatable, i want to disable a button (the button `deleteButton`), so I wrote this code :

```
$('#equipmentList th').click( function() {
    hideButtonEditAndDelete();
});

function hideButtonEditAndDelete() {
    $("#modifyButton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $( "#deleteButton" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");

//fix for firefox

if($.browser.mozilla){
    $("#modifyButton").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
    $("#deleteButton").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
}}
```

Everything goes well until the sort is ending because, after, my button is enabled by jQuery; or something else. so I'm looking for capture event at the end of sorting order to disable my button

Comment: @user571627: hi, welcome to Stack Overflow; it's worth taking a few moments to read the [Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), and, if you'd like, to register with the site (so you get to use your own name, rather than user123456) =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a callback that is made every time that the table is redrawn and can be accessed on the fnDrawCallback:

```
$('#someTable').dataTable({
        "fnInitComplete": function() {
            // after table is intialised do something here
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            // after table is redrawndo something here
            console.log("redrawn");
        },
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sScrollY": "242px",
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "aaSorting": [[2, 'asc']],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sSortDataType": "dom-checkbox", "sWidth": "3%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "8%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "10%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "15%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "8%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "9%" },
            { "bSortable": true, "sWidth": "6%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "2%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "7%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "13%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "2%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "7%" },
            { "bSortable": false, "sWidth": "10%" }
        ]
    });
```

More info on callbacks here:

http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks